# To find out file is in use other than lsof command in linux

Tags: shell

I am writing shell script.In that I am iterating through file which contains list of some logfiles.I want to find out whether each of these file is currently in use or not.If not in use then I want to delete that file?I tried lsof command but it is not supporting.Is there any other way to acheive the same goal?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `fuser` command. `fuser` returns a list of pids of processes using the file. Try the following code

```
if ! fuser /path/to/file
then
     rm /path/to/file
fi
```

Comment: this won't always work. try `vim foo.txt` then in another terminal : `fuser foo.txt`